# Update user avatar profil Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, crud

I have a little problem about update avatar pic of my user.

I have a polymorph relation table for Image and when i update info of my user profile and upload new avatar in my DB he create a new entry and not updated the current id of my table Images.

Table Images Id|path|Imageable_id|imageable_type|created_at

My UsersController method update

```
public function update($id){

    $rules =[
        /*'lastname' => 'min:3|string',
        'firstname' => 'min:3|string',
        'username'=> 'min:4|unique:users',
        'mail'    => ' email|unique:users',
        'birthday' => 'date_format:d-m-Y|before:today',
        'country'=>'min:3',
        'type_street'=>'min:3',
        'number'=>'min:1|numeric',
        'street'=>'min:4|string',
        'complementary_street'=>'min:2|string',
        'town'=>'min:2|string',
        'zip'=>'min:4|numeric',
        'phone_home'=>'min:10|numeric',
        'phone_mobile'=>'min:10|numeric',
        'image_path'=>'image|max:1000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',*/
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('/profil/'.$id)
            ->with('alert_error','Merci de corriger les erreurs');

    }else{
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->lastname     =   Input::get('lastname');
        $user->firstname    =   Input::get('firstname');
        $user->username     =   Input::get('username');
        $user->mail         =   Input::get('mail');
        $user->birthday     =   Input::get('birthday');
        $user->adresse->type_street  =   Input::get('type_street');
        $user->adresse->number       =   Input::get('number');
        $user->adresse->street       =   Input::get('street');
        $user->adresse->complementary_street       =   Input::get('complementary_street');
        $user->adresse->town         =   Input::get('town');
        $user->adresse->zip          =   Input::get('zip');
        $user->adresse->country      =   Input::get('country');
        $user->adresse->phone_home      =   Input::get('phone_home');
        $user->adresse->phone_mobile      =   Input::get('phone_mobile');

        if(Input::hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = Image::find($id);

            $file = Input::file('avatar');
            $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file = $file->move('img/avatar/', $name);
            $input['path'] = 'img/avatar/'.$name;
            $input['imageable_id'] = $user->id;
            $input['imageable_type'] = 'User';

            $avatar = new Image($input);
            $avatar->save();
        }

        $user->adresse->save();

        return Redirect::to('/profil/'.$id)
            ->with('alert_success','Modification sauvegardé avec succès');

    }
}
```

Can you help me for this feature i don't understand why no updated of current id of my entry and create new One .

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your find `$avatar = Image::find($id);` with a new instance `$avatar = new Image($input);`